# Покушение на убийство

Tags: значение-слов, согласование, смысл

Это выражение знают все, но я вдумался в его смысл. Покуситься можно на жизнь, на имущество — одним словом, на что-то с целью это уничтожить.
По сути, **покушение на убийство** — это не попытка убийства, а действия, направленные на то, чтобы этому убийству помешать.
Разъясните мне, пожалуйста, в чем я не прав.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то подобные двусмысленности встречаются в языке. Причем - по самым разным причинам, все тут не обсудишь. Но вот как пример: тут недавно обсуждалось "дать зарок" "заречься" - сделать что-то или не делать чего-то. 
Или вот просторечное "занять" в значении "одолжить".

Но тут все даже проще.
"Покуситься" не несет смысла "с целью это уничтожить". Это просто некое действие, направленное на достижение какой-то цели, обычно - преступной  или неблаговидной. 
"Покушение на жизнь" - это просто стяжение от "покушение на (лишение) жизни".
А покушение на убийство - это именно попытка убийства.